# How do alpha particles emit the heleum spectrum without electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation, hydrogen

By definition, alpha particles do not have any electrons. This, in turn, should mean they do not emit a spectrum because a light spectrum is caused by electrons jumping between orbitals. Yet it is by alpha particles emitting a spectrum that Rutherford determined them to be helium nuclei (see here for details https://history.aip.org/exhibits/rutherford/sections/alpha-particles-atom.html).

Comment: Because as they propagate they can acquire electrons via exchange with background gas. Such charge exchange is a well studied phenomenon.

Comment: If there were other gases in the container Rutherford isolated the alpha particles in, extra light spectra would have shown up in Rutherford's experiment. These light spectrums should have made it very difficult for Rutherford to pick out helium spectrum. Yet according to Wikipedia, the helium spectrum was could be clearly seen ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Rutherford#Early_life_and_education for details).

Comment: The helium spectrum is different from the othe gases, of course. If you start with no He and start seeing He, where did it come from?

Comment: You are correct, it had to come from the Helium. But if the Helium gained electrons from a background gas, then Rutherford should not have been able to pick out the He spectrum from the garbled mess of various light spectrums. So it seems we have a conundrum: that Helium emitted its spectrum but there was no way that it could have had electrons at that time.

Comment: Why do you think the spectra could not be distinguished?

Comment: Yes, it seems I am wrong about that. By comparing the spectrums emitted from the glass before and after the alpha particles were released would have enabled Rutherford to distinguish the helium spectra. Yet it seems that I did not have to concoct this argument to prove that this conundrum exists. According to Wikipedia, the tube Rutherford emitted these alpha particles into was evacuated, which prevents the possibility of there being a background gas.

Comment: *"According to Wikipedia, the tube Rutherford emitted these alpha particles into was evacuated, which prevents the possibility of there being a background gas."* How low of a pressure was the "vacuum"? Perhaps there was plenty of remaining non-helium gas to lend charge to the alpha particles.

Comment: If there was plenty of background gas present, then other light spectrums should have been very visible. Yet when the experiment is described, there is no mention of other light spectrums besides the helium spectrum. Since a detail like this would be an important aspect of the experiment, it seems unlikely to me that it would be left out in the description of the experiment.  But wherever I look there is no mention of any other light spectrums. This has lead me to believe that there was not any significant amount of background gas in the vile the alpha particles were in.

Answer (score 4):

The paper usually referenced (e.g. by Wikipedia) as the identification of the $\alpha$ particle as the Helium nucleus is "XXIV. Spectrum of the Radium Emanation", E. Rutherford and T. Royds, Phil. Mag. Vol. 16. No. 92 (Aug. 1908 - [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/14786440808636511)). Details on how the $\alpha$ particles were isolated and purified are given in "XXIII. Experiments with the radium emanation. (1) The volume of the emanations", E. Rutherford, Phil. Mag. 16(92) 300-312 (1908, [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/14786440808636510)). Now, the possible linking of the $\alpha$ particle and He had existed for a while, such as in "XLI. The mass and velocity of the $\alpha$ particles expelled from radium and actinium", E. Rutherford, Phil. Mag. Vol. 12 No. 70  348-371 (Oct. 1906 - [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/14786440609463549)). However, such indirect proof was not considered sufficient.

The experiment is described in the 1908 paper pretty well. The "radium emanations" where captured in a glass tube. After various purifying steps (condensation with liquid air, reaction with potash to remove carbon dioxide, ...). What was left was sealed in a glass tube with platinum electrodes. The electrodes were used to excite the remaining gas. The spectrum of the discharge was observed visually and photographed as well.

To quote the 1908 paper:

> In order to photograph
>   the spectrum, a spectrograph with a glass prism of two inches
>   base was used. The length of the spectrum on the plate
>   between $\lambda$ 5000 and $\lambda$ 4000 was 1.5 cms. Arrangements
>   were made so that visual observations of the wave-lengths
>   could be made by the Hilger spectroscope while the plate
>   was being exposed. Two photographs were taken before the
>   emanation spectrum ran out. The first (photograph 1) showed
>   about thirty of the more intense emanation lines. The second
>   (photograph 2), which had a much longer exposure, showed
>   over a hundred lines. A helium tube was used for comparison
>   purposes, and its spectrum obtained above and below the
>   emanation spectrum. The plates were measured up with the
>   aid of a Kayser's measuring machine. The wave-lengths
>   were deduced with the aid of the Hartmann dispersion
>   formula

So, the emission spectrum of the $\alpha$ particles was not measured as they were emitted. Instead, the $\alpha$s were released from the radium into a glass tube, separated through purification, and then used in a discharge tube. The direct comparison with a He lamp seals the deal. (As for the 'emanation spectrum' running out, recall that He diffuses quite easily through glass so it leaks out quickly.)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the tube was evacuated before the alpha particles were emitted. The way the alpha particles entered the evacuated tube was by penetrating a very thin window. This narrative of how the alpha particles were isolated seems to be in conflict with the narrative of the paper you describe. Could you please send me the link to where you got the information so I could make sure that I'm not being lead astray?

Comment: @AnthonyDucharme - The DOI link and human-readable reference are given in the answer. I’ll review to be sure I understood the paper as well.

Comment: Thank you for showing me where I could find the paper. Upon examination, I found it to be a narrative detailing Rutherford's endeavors with the radium spectrum rather than the alpha particle spectrum. This, in turn, means all the information described in this specifically related to Rutherford's studies with Radium. If it were not for the fact that Wikipedia describes a different isolation method than the one described in this paper on Radium I would say it can reasonably be inferred that Rutherford used the same purification method in both his experiments involving Radium and alpha particles.

Comment: Wikipedia's source for Rutherford's experiment is this https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/1908/rutherford-lecture.html . If you are interested in reading it yourself, I would suggest searching for the key phrase,"While the whole train of evidence we," and begin from there.

Comment: @AnthonyDucharme - Given that the optical emission of the 'radium emanation' matches that of helium (and not radium), I think the 1908 papers are, in fact, what you are looking for.

Comment: @John Custer -Well from what I read, Rutherford's Nobel speech contradicts the methods described in that paper, so it seems we have a conundrum on our hands.

Comment: @AnthonyDucharme - not really - the second paper linked to above essentially follows Rutherford's speech. The thin-walled glass tube with radium in it is heated inside a larger tube. When the radium melts it releases the He from the bulk, and the He then diffuses quickly through the thin glass tube into the larger tube.

Comment: @John Custer- Thank you for correcting me. Upon rereading the Nobel Speech, I see that you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Protons or neutrons can also emit photons. You don’t necessarily need electrons. https://www.quora.com/Can-an-accelerated-proton-emit-electromagnetic-radiation

Comment: Yes, this is true, but if the light spectrum were produced by neutrons and protons emitting photons how exactly would you explain the discrete lines and frequencies of the light?

Comment: This is the question that your response brings to mind.

Comment: @AnthonyDucharme electrons are all identical and it’s there different arrangements and combinations that give them specific spectrums or energy levels. And just like electrons a nucleus and its arrangement of protons and neutrons will create different spectrums.